# Integrate angular material with primeNg

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-material-6

In my project i was using primeNG but now i want to use angular material but i am getting Multi error when i install material and serve the project

```
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css ./src/styles.scss ./node_modules/line-awesome/dist/css/line-awesome.css ./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css ./node_modules/morris.js/morris.css ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css ./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css ./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\Workspace\zeplin\hcmfrontend\node_modules\line-awesome\dist\css\line-awesome.css' in 'E:\Workspace\zeplin\hcmfrontend'
```

is is possible to use both the libraries as currently i wont be able to uninstall primeNg for throughout the project as it has high dependency on the project but i want to use material, is there any way possible

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.15",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^14.0.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^8.0.3",
    "angular-io-slimscroll": "^2.3.3",
    "angular-morris-js": "^0.3.0",
    "angular-randomcolor": "^1.0.3",
    "angular2-click-to-edit": "^1.0.52",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular4-slimscroll": "^1.0.5",
    "autosize": "^4.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^7.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "latest-version": "^5.1.0",
    "line-awesome": "github:icons8/line-awesome",
    "material-icons": "^0.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.6",
    "ng-fullcalendar": "^1.7.1",
    "ng-http-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "ng-starrating": "^1.0.11",
    "ng-trim-value-accessor": "^2.0.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng4-eonasdan-datetimepicker-hirwan": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-animating-datepicker": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-avatar": "^3.7.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "ngx-chips": "2.0.2",
    "ngx-iq-datepicker": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-rating": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-slimscroll": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-textarea-autosize": "^2.0.3",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.0.0",
    "raphael": "^2.2.8",
    "replace-in-file": "^4.2.0",
    "rollbar": "^2.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

these are the dependencies installed in my project,
can someone help me with this please

Comment: It is not able to find `line-awesome.css`. Check where you have used it, most probably in `angular.json` under styles, verify if you have specified the `line-awesome.css` path correctly

Comment: (WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-typeahead.js 1488:12-24 "export 'isObservable' was not found in 'rxjs')

this is the error which comes now

Comment: You are allowe to use material with primeng. Because now it is throwing new error. May be you could try this approach. Stop the project and do the `npm install` then serve it. Let us know if you face any error